# What would happen when a pilot receives a message about Dead Reckoning Fault?

Tags: navigation

Dead Reckoning Fault will lead to some restrictions of the flight. What will happen after receiving this message?

Comment: In what aircraft?

Comment: In any aircraft! Airbus, Boeing and etc.

Comment: How would this message be sent:ECAM/EFIS, ..? and why? Could you point to some documentation, or tell us what you know about this message?

Comment: It would be sent by ECAM or on the panel.